# Sharepoint REST api HTTP Error 403: Forbidden getting versions

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, 403

I'm able to get the value of the file:

`url = sharepoint_app_url + "_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + file_path + "')/$value"`

However when I want to get the versions or a specific version I get the 403 forbidden

`url1 = sharepoint_app_url + "_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + file_path + "')/Versions"`

Comment: What permissions you have on the file, read/edit/full control?

Comment: I have read write permissions

Answer (score 0):

Does your permission level has the checkbox "View versions"

enabled?/_layouts/15/editrole.aspx?role=Edit

[image]

Comment: Where do I find that ?

Comment: https://[yoursitecollection]/_layouts/15/editrole.aspx?role=Edit

Where role= your permission level (Read, Contribute, Full Control, etc)

You can also go to https://[yoursitecollection]/_layouts/15/user.aspx
And use the button permission levels in the Ribbon

Comment: How are you setting up your connection to SharePoint? If you are using clientid/secret (ACS) then permissions have to be set using the appinv.aspx file

Comment: yes permission have been added in appinv.aspx, 

<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="Read" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list" Right="Write"/>
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list" Right="FullControl"/>
 
</AppPermissionRequests>

Comment: What happens when you go in the browser to the versions:
https://[yoursitecollection]/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/Items(2)/Versions
Replace listname and id with your values

Comment: Via the browser, when i'm connected with my username and password. I can see the Versions. when I use a request with my token, I get the 403 forbidden. I can retrieve the $value of latest as mentioned in the question

Comment: I have created an app with appregnew with same permissions added with appinv. In my tenant I get the versions. Your appinv xml didn't work for me. The scopes have to start with http://

Comment: Didn't work for anything ? or just getting the versions ? weird I can get the latest document with these configs...

Comment: Yes I was able to get all my versions

Comment: When you used my appinv xml what didn't work for you ?

Comment: I copied it from your comment. But the scope is not copied correct. The "http://" part was missing. I think it is stripped from the comment.
Have you tried other items?

Comment: Did you create a token from client id and secret and then retrieved the data via token ?
or you fetched the versions via the browser ?

Comment: I created a token with clientid/secret in PostMan and requested the versions using:
/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Ontwikkel/Test/test.aspx')/Versions
Passing the token in the header

Comment: Maybe retrust the app or create a new one?

Comment: I see... it is an organization app.

Comment: Just use appinv again and reset the permissions. Maybe that works. Otherwise try another list and item. Maybe there is something wrong with your list or item

Comment: I will try that, thanks

Comment: Did you have any success with your app?

Comment: Hi Danny, not really... waiting for Microsoft's support